How to speed up a code which uses FindRoot in NDEigensystem?
I am trying to find the Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for a solitonic model. The code that I am using to achieve my goal is given below:
f[r_, q_] := ((-1 + r^2) (q^2 + r^2 + r^4))/r^6

g[r_, q_] := -1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4

h[r_, q_] := (q^2 (10 - 8 r^2) - 4 r^2 (-2 + r^4))/r^3

V[r_, x_, k_, q_] := (k^2 r^6)/((-1 + r^2) (q^2 + r^2 + r^4)) + 
  4 r^4 x^2

delyb[r_, q_] := (-8 r^2 + 6 r^6 + q^2 (-9 + 8 r^2))/(
 2 r^3 Sqrt[-1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4])

Veff[r_, x_, k_, q_] := 
 V[r, x, k, q] + (Sqrt[g[r, q]] D[delyb[r, q], r] - (delyb[r, q])^2)

s1[r_, q_] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[g[\[Chi], q]], {\[Chi], 1.1, r}]

rsol[s_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
 r1 /. FindRoot[s1[r1, q] == s, {r1, 1}, Evaluated -> False, 
   Method -> "Newton"]

eq[s2_, k_, q_] := (-\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\((\[Psi][s, x])\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s, s\)]\((\[Psi][s, x])\)\) + 
   Veff[rsol[s2, q], x, k, q] \[Psi][s, x])

eig[k_, q_] := 
 NDEigensystem[{eq[s, k, q], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][s, x] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][s, x], {s, 
   0.1, 0.8}, {x, -10, 10}, 200]

{EigValues, EigFunctions} = eig[4, 0.2]

It has been running for 15 hours now.
Edit
I tried making a separate table for the output of FindRoot using this code:
ClearAll[f, g, h, V, delyb, Veff, s1, rsol, eq, eig];

f[r_, q_] := ((-1 + r^2) (q^2 + r^2 + r^4))/r^6;

g[r_, q_] := -1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4;

h[r_, q_] := (q^2 (10 - 8 r^2) - 4 r^2 (-2 + r^4))/r^3;

V[r_, x_, k_, q_] := (k^2 r^6)/((-1 + r^2) (q^2 + r^2 + r^4)) + 
   4 r^4 x^2;

delyb[r_, 
   q_] := (-8 r^2 + 6 r^6 + 
     q^2 (-9 + 8 r^2))/(2 r^3 Sqrt[-1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4]);

Veff[r_, x_, k_, q_] := 
  V[r, x, k, q] + (Sqrt[g[r, q]] D[delyb[r, q], r] - (delyb[r, q])^2);

s1[r_, q_] := 
  NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[g[chi, q]], {chi, 1.1, r}, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

rsolGrid = 
  Table[{s, 0.2, 
    r1 /. FindRoot[s1[r1, 0.2] == s, {r1, 1}, Method -> "Newton", 
      Evaluated -> False]}, {s, 0.1, 0.8, 0.01}, {q, 0.1, 1.0, 0.1}];

rsolTable[s_, q_] := 
 SelectFirst[Flatten[rsolGrid, 1], #[[1]] == s && #[[2]] == q &]

eq[s2_, k_, 
  q_] := (-D[\[Psi][s, x], {x, 2}] - D[\[Psi][s, x], {s, 2}] + 
   Veff[rsolTable[s2, q][[3]], x, k, q] \[Psi][s, x])

eig[k_, q_] := 
 NDEigensystem[{eq[s, k, q], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][s, x] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][s, x], {s, 
   0.1, 0.8}, {x, -10, 10}, 2, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]

{EigValues, EigFunctions} = eig[4, 0.2];

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Using Interpolation reduces the computation time by almost $95$%
f[r_, q_] := ((-1 + r^2) (q^2 + r^2 + r^4))/r^6;

g[r_, q_] := -1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4;

h[r_, q_] := (q^2 (10 - 8 r^2) - 4 r^2 (-2 + r^4))/r^3;

V[r_, x_, k_, q_] := (k^2 r^6)/((-1 + r^2) (q^2 + r^2 + r^4)) + 
   4 r^4 x^2;

delyb[r_, 
   q_] := (-8 r^2 + 6 r^6 + 
     q^2 (-9 + 8 r^2))/(2 r^3 Sqrt[-1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4]);

Veff[r_, x_, k_, q_] := 
  V[r, x, k, q] + (Sqrt[g[r, q]] D[delyb[r, q], r] - (delyb[r, q])^2);

s1[r_, q_] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[g[chi, q]], {chi, 1.1, r}]

(*Precompute r(s,q) for a range of s and q values*)
precomputedR = 
  Table[{s, q, 
    r1 /. FindRoot[s1[r1, q] == s, {r1, 1}, Evaluated -> False, 
      Method -> {"Newton"}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6]}, {s, 0.1, 0.8, 0.001}, {q, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];

(*Interpolate r(s,q) based on precomputed values*)
rInterp = Interpolation[Flatten[precomputedR, 1], Method -> "Spline"]; 

(*Simplified equation using precomputed r(s,q)*)
simplifiedEq[s2_, k_, q_] := 
 Simplify[(-D[\[Psi][s, x], {x, 2}] - D[\[Psi][s, x], {s, 2}] + 
    Veff[rInterp[s2, q], x, k, q] \[Psi][s, x])]

(*Compute the eigenvalue problem using precomputed r(s,q)*)
eig[k_, q_] := 
 NDEigensystem[{simplifiedEq[s, k, q], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][s, x] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][s, x], {s, 
   0.1, 0.8}, {x, -10, 10}, 100, 
  Method -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 10^5}]

{EigValues, EigFunctions} = eig[4, 0.2]

